# How to get id vertex by name?

Tags: c++, c, igraph

If I want to get the name by id vertex i can use this funcion: `VAS(g, "name",id)` 
but if I want the opposite way,to get the id by the name, how can I do that?

Comment: I've never used `igraph`, but since no-one else has answered: after a quick check of the documentation, I think I'm right in saying that `VAS` looks up an attribute for a vertex in the graph. If your question is how to find the ID of the vertex (or vertices) with a particular value for a specified attribute, then I guess you can iterate through all the vertices in the graph, check the attribute and accumulate a list of vertices that match the criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

igraph doesn't provide, on its own, a means to look up vertices by name, and for good reason - mapping from name to ID is a more challenging problem than mapping from ID to name, which is a simple array lookup operation.  You could iterate through all the vertices and stop at the one that matches, but this is inefficient for large graphs (O(n) in the number of vertices).  A faster way is to use some sort of associative array data structure, such as the `dict` in @Jasc's answer, and use the names as keys and ID's as values.  (You'll need to keep this index in sync with the graph if you change it.)  C, on its own, or the standard C library provide no such data structure, but there are many implementations available, for instance the [GHash structure](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Hash-Tables.html) found in glib.

Comment: +1; this is exactly what I would have written as one of the authors of igraph. I would only add that it is possible to replace the default attribute handler of igraph, so the OP could theoretically extend igraph's default attribute handling mechanism so it automatically maintains a reverse mapping of names to ids. But this is not implemented in the core library.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following on the igrah website or mailinglist.

```
g = igraph.Graph(0, directed=True)
g.add_vertices(2)
g.vs[0]["name"] = "Bob"
g.vs[1]["name"] = "Bill"
# build a dict for all vertices to lookup ids by name
name2id = dict((v, k) for k, v in enumerate(g.vs["name"]))
# access specific vertices like this:
id_bob = name2id["Bob"]
print(g.vs[id_bob]["name"])
```

Comment: This looks like Python, and it looks good, but the original poster tagged the question "C" or "C++"